# Was it necessary for the Kais to let Gohan's energy be drained for Buu?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

I'm confused as to why Supreme Kai paralyzed Gohan for his energy to be drained.

Couldn't they have just eliminated Babidi so that Buu wouldn't be resurrected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly the reason was because the Kai didn't know where Babidi was hiding. He used Gohan as bait, and then was able to follow Babidi's henchman back to the wizard's ship. If he hadn't done that, who knows how the story would have unfolded from there.

Also, it wasn't just Gohan's energy that restored Majin Buu, but also energy taken from the fights within Babidi's ship.

Knowing the characters of the Saiyan Z-fighters, they wouldn't have stopped Buu from resurrecting anyway. They would just want to fight him.

Comment: Vegeta yes would want Buu resurrected so he could fight him at full strength since he did a similar thing with Cell and if i remember correctly he joined Babidi's side for that reason (i think, i remember him being Marjin Vegeta at one point) but Goku and Gohan would want to avoid fighting.

Answer (score 1):

As jphager2's answer points out, they needed to know where Babidi was hiding. The Supreme Kais were willing to let Gohan's energy be drained because they never thought he, and the other Z fighters, were so strong. Maybe if they knew that Gohan's energy would fill half of Buu's energy need they would not have taken the risk.